# How to check if last character is integer in raw_input

Tags: python

basically i want the script to check the last digit of the raw_input  to see if it's integer or not. if integer print true, else print false

here is the code:

```
word = raw_input("input your alphanumeric word:")
end = re.search(r'\d+$', word)
if end is not None:
    print "numeric digit should be last"
else 
    print "true"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is an overkill for problems as simple as this. Simply index the last element `word[-1]` and check if its a digit via the builtin String method [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

```
word[-1].isdigit()
```

Note, you may have to consider the fact that the word may be an empty string and have to handle it appropriately.

```
bool(word) and word[-1].isdigit()
```

or as suggested by @iCodez use slicing instead of indexing, as slicing would not throw index error for empty string

```
word[-1:].isdigit()
```

**Example**

```
>>> word = raw_input("input your alphanumeric word:")
input your alphanumeric word:asdf
>>> bool(word) and word[-1].isdigit()
False
>>> word = raw_input("input your alphanumeric word:")
input your alphanumeric word:asd1
>>> bool(word) and word[-1].isdigit()
True
>>> word = raw_input("input your alphanumeric word:")
input your alphanumeric word:
>>> bool(word) and word[-1].isdigit()
False
```

Comment: If the string can be empty, you could do: `word[-1:].isdigit()`.  Slicing does not throw an error for out-of-bounds indexes.

Comment: @iCodez: Yes, I agree. Nice suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the last character of the string using slicing `[-1]`, and use the string method `isdigit` to see if it is a number.

```
s1 = 'hello world'
s2 = 'hello again3'

>>> s1[-1].isdigit()
False

>>> s2[-1].isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print 'true' if re.search(r'\d$', word) else 'false'
```

You could also use:

```
print 'true' if word[-1].isdigit() else 'false'
```

...but this will throw an `IndexError` if the word is zero-length.